# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (50,50,512) (3,) (50,50,512) while converting tensor to image in pytorch

Tags: conv-neural-network, pytorch, tensor, vgg-net, style-transfer

I'm doing a neural style transfer. I'm trying to reconstruct the output of the convolutional layer conv4_2 of the VGG19 network.

```
def get_features(image, model):

    layers = {'0': 'conv1_1', '5': 'conv2_1',  '10': 'conv3_1', 
              '19': 'conv4_1', '21': 'conv4_2', '28': 'conv5_1'}
    x = image
    features = {}

    for name, layer in model._modules.items():
        x = layer(x)

        if name in layers:
            features[layers[name]] = x   

    return features

content_img_features = get_features(content_img, vgg)
style_img_features   = get_features(style_img, vgg)

target_content = content_img_features['conv4_2']
```

content_img_features is a dict that contains the output of every layer.
target_content is a tensor of shape `torch.Size([1, 512, 50, 50])`

This is the method I use to plot the image using the tensor. It works fine for the input image as well as the final output.

```
def tensor_to_image(tensor):
    image = tensor.clone().detach()
    image = image.numpy().squeeze()
    image = image.transpose(1, 2, 0)
    image *= np.array((0.22, 0.22, 0.22))+ np.array((0.44, 0.44, 0.44))
    image = image.clip(0, 1)
    return image

image = tensor_to_image(target_content)
fig = plt.figure()
plt.imshow(image)
```

But this throws the error,

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-188-a75a5f0743bb> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 image = tensor_to_image(target_content)
      3 fig = plt.figure()
      4 plt.imshow(image)

<ipython-input-186-e9385dbc4a85> in tensor_to_image(tensor)
      3     image = image.numpy().squeeze()
      4     image = image.transpose(1, 2, 0)
----> 5     image *= np.array((0.22, 0.22, 0.22))+ np.array((0.44, 0.44, 0.44))
      6     image = image.clip(0, 1)
      7     return image

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (50,50,512) (3,) (50,50,512)
```

This is the initial transformation I apply to the image before passing to the cnn layers,

```
def transformation(img):

    tasks = tf.Compose([tf.Resize(400), tf.ToTensor(),
            tf.Normalize((0.44,0.44,0.44),(0.22,0.22,0.22))])
    img = tasks(img)[:3,:,:].unsqueeze(0)    

    return img
```

How do I fix this? Is there another way to reconstruct the image from the convolution layer?

Comment: I think I gave an answer for your question, do you mind marking it answered? If not, then please point out in a comment where you think my answer is lacking, so I can address it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `tensor_to_image` method only works for 3 channel images. Your input to the network is 3 channels, so is the final output, therefore it works fine there. But you cannot do the same at an internal high dimensional activation.

Essentially the problem is that you try to apply a channel-wise normalization, but you have parameters for only three channels, that's why that particular line fails. You would need a 512 element vector of means and standard deviations. So for example this would work:

```
image *= np.random.random([512]) + np.random.random([512])
```

However the fundamental problem is still that you try to visualize a high dimensional, 512 channel image, instead a traditional 3 channel (RGB) image. You may try to visualize channels separately, or in groups of 3, but still it might not be really useful.